# Como barrar o envio do package-lock.json pelo gitignore?

Tags: linux, git, terminal

Não estou conseguindo "ignorar" o envio do `package-lock.json` para o gitlab, quando executo o `git status` ele me aparece para ser enviado. Segue um print mostrando o `.gitignore` e o meu terminal ao executar o git status.

[image: Executando o git status]

Arquivo .gitignore

[image: Arquivo .gitignore]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se você deseja **remover** este arquivo do repositório e fazer com que ele não fique mais versionado no mesmo, você precisa adicionar ele no `.gitignore` e remover ele usando o comando abaixo:

```
git rm --cached package-lock.json
```

Agora, se você deseja **manter** este arquivo no repositório mas não quer que qualquer nova mudança nele possa ser commitada, você deve usar o comando

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged package-lock.json
```

Se quiser voltar a rastrear as alterações nele:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged package-lock.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você quer que o arquivo `package-lock.json` não seja adicionado ao commit. Desta forma ele tambem não vai ser enviado ao para o repositorio do Gitlab.

Se for isso é so utilizar o comando `git rm package-lock.json`.

Assim o git não vai gerencialo mais.

Answer (score -1):

As demais respostas focaram no como fazer, mas não o **por quê não deve ser feito**.
O package-lock.json contém a informação completa de versões de cada dependências utilizadas na compilação do seu projeto (incluindo dependência de dependência), ao contrário do package.json que indica as dependências necessárias pelo seu código. Apenas com o package-lock.json garantimos que não teremos surpresas com um novo build do projeto. Mais detalhes em [Devo subir o arquivo package-lock.json para o github?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/477545/devo-subir-o-arquivo-package-lock-json-para-o-github)

Sei que é uma pergunta antiga, mas terminei chegando aqui ao pesquisar por "package-lock.json gitignore". Achei melhor avisar outro desavisado (como eu... )

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/late-answers/388433)

Comment: Marcos, o texto da resposta já contém toda informação necessária sobre pq devemos versionar o package-lock.json (garantir que o build poderá ser reproduzido corretamente). O link da outra pergunta é apenas para dar o devido crédito. 
Ou eu deveria incluir as instruções do Git, conforme já apresentada nas resposta do Dherik?