# Devo subir o arquivo package-lock.json para o github?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github

Sei que a pasta `node_modules` por questão até de segurança não deve ser enviada para o `github`, então adiciono ela no arquivo `.gitignore`... mas e quanto ao arquivo `package-lock.json` q tem muitas informações? É seguro enviar ele para o `github`? Ou devo enviar apenas o arquivo `package.json` e excluir o `package-lock.json`? E caso não deva enviar, como faço para remover os que já enviei?

Comment: Deve sim, pois irá garantir exatamente a versões usadas no original, pois as vezes as pessoas adicionam um pacote com um esquema de versão como 1.*, o que pode ser conflitante acaso exista um update de 1.1 para 1.2, por exemplo, o que nem sempre mantêm a versão, então o ideal é sim usar o lock, claro que você pode usar bem o versionamento dos pacotes, mas se é algo que vai trabalhar com mais pessoas isso poderia complicar, então o lock pode ajudar a evitar problemas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É recomendado sim. Isso garante que a versão das dependências vai sempre ser a mesma independente do ambiente em que a aplicação for configurada.

Geralmente quando instalamos dependências utilizando `npm install dependency` a versão acaba ficando com algum nível de wildcard. Aqui já tivemos problemas com dependências com versões diferentes, no estilo: Projeto foi implementado, e a dependência x foi instalada na versão 1.2.3, após alguns meses, ao fazer o deploy para produção, estava indo com a versão 1.2.15, e isso estava causando problemas no projeto em produção. Sei que supostamente não deveria acontecer nada, pois no conceito do semver, é que alterações no último dígito não deveriam influenciar, mas não conseguimos garantir que todas as dependências estejam versionando corretamente.

Ou seja, o recomendado é sempre versionar o `package-lock.json`, e mantê-lo sempre atualizado a cada adição, atualização e remoção de dependências do projeto.